# Problem using Seq.cast

Tags: .net, f#, seq

Using `Seq.cast` seems to constantly fail, even for something as simple as the following:

```
let xor c = Seq.cast c |> Seq.reduce (^^^)
xor [1;3]       // Works, assuming because no cast is necessary
xor ['a';'b']   // Fails
xor [2u]        // Fails
```

The latter two fail with Specified Cast is not valid. What am I missing?

I'm trying to use `Seq.cast` to convert a bunch of stuff to `uint16`, but for some reason it always fails (even if I annotate it with `Seq.cast<uint32>`). What's up with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe this is because `Seq.cast` will only do type *casts*, rather that type *coercion*: you want `Seq.map uint32 c |> Seq.reduce (^^^)`.

The difference between casting and coercing is that while casting changes the static type a value is interpreted as without changing it's dynamic type, (eg: I know this `Animal` is really a `Dog`), coercing creates a completely new value ... at least from the language point of view. The split in the CLR seems to be pretty much between value types (coercing) and reference types (casting), which makes it a bit easier to keep straight.

Comment: Oh I see. Seq.cast is trying to cast the container and not its contents

Comment: Not quite: while `Seq.cast<uint32> ['a'; 'b']` does cast the `char seq` to a `uint32 seq` (successfully, even), the error happens when the values are enumerated: when the `IEnumerable<uint32>.Current` property is read, it tries and fails to cast the `char` to a `uint32`, when it needs to coerce it, with the `uint32` function.

Comment: I meant `IEnumerator`, not `IEnumerable` of course. If it's not clear, `Seq` is just an alias for `IEnumerable`.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I had the `c|> Seq.map uint32 |> Seq.reduce (^^^)` solution, but was wondering why the example failed.

Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 3):

See also

[What does this C# code look like in F#? (part one: expressions and statements)](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!725.entry)

which discusses how casts can mean (at least) 4 different operations in C#, and how each of those different operations maps to specific F# functionality.